# Laravel 5.4 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

So I am short on info as I have no idea whats going on.

So when I go to `mysite.com/login` I get `NotFoundHttpException` This just happened while I was creating another view.

If I go to `homeController` and change the index view to `/auth.login` and going to mysite.com shows the login page.

My routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name("main");

Route::auth();
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Route::auth()`, try this instead `Auth::routes()`

Comment: IDE editor says it's unknown and it did not change the outcome of mysite.com/login

Comment: @joveice are you using laravel's default authentication scaffold?

Comment: I guess I am, have not changed anything on it as I'm in the start of the project

Comment: If you want to use laravel's default authentication boilerplate, run `php artisan make:auth` in your command line terminal. This would create the login, register and reset password views in your `resources\views\auth` folder and create the necessary controllers in your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth` directory.
It should also add the `Auth::routes()` to your route file

Comment: Oh, Well then yea I'm running the default, thats the command I did.

Comment: Note sure what it does, but it did not fix the issue :(

Comment: try this `php artisan route:list`. take a screenshot of the output or copy and paste here

Comment: I'm getting Error, failed to open stream: Permission denied. This was in a elevated cmd